# Combine two queries results where matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two SQL Server queries that return a large amount of data.

```
  Query One
  -----------

  SELECT PRODUCT, NAME
  FROM TABLEONE


  Query Two
  -----------

  SELECT PRODUCT, VALUE
  FROM TABLETWO
```

And the results will look something like this

Q1:

```
 PRODUCT      NAME
 ---------------------
 A            DEMO
 B            DEMO
 NULL         DEMO
 C            DEMO
 D            DEMO
```

Q2:

```
 PRODUCT      VALUE
 --------------------
 A            12.50
 B            13.40
 C            99.99
 D            63.44
 E            55.33
 F            77.33
```

I need to add the `Value` amount from Query 2 to the Query 1 result where the Product name matches, ignoring the null values.

The result should be:

```
 PRODUCT      NAME      VALUE
 ----------------------------------
 A            DEMO      12.50
 B            DEMO      13.40
 NULL         DEMO      NULL
 C            DEMO      99.99
 D            DEMO      63.44
```

I was thinking about using UNION to combine them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a `left join`:

```
select q1.*, q2.value
from q1 left join
     q2
     on q1.product = q2.product
```